# C - Segmentation fault after open a file from a method

Tags: c, file, printf

I'm trying to refactor a pice of code, that works correctly, to make it more modular but when I try to encapsulate it on a method, the program shows a segmentation fault. I really don't know why it happens because I had copied literally the code and put it on the method and it is supposed to be the same.

**Main Code**

```
char file_name[20];
FILE *file;

...

printf("File name > ");
scanf("%s", file_name);

file = fopen(file_name, "r");
if(file == NULL)
{
    printf("¡Error loading file!\n");
    return 1;
}

printf("\nRows > ");

...
```

**Method**

```
void open_file(FILE *file)
{
    char file_name[20];

    printf("File name > ");
    scanf("%s", file_name);

    file = fopen(file_name, "r");
}
```

I know that the failure is after open the file because the last printf prints the escape sequence

**Main Code using the method**

```
char file_name[20];
FILE *file;

...

open_file(file);
if(file == NULL)
{
    printf("¡Error opening the file!\n");
    return 1;
}

printf("\nRows > ");

...
```

I know that this refactor is unnecessary, but once tried I want to know why it doesn't work, because I had copy literally the first code and had put it in a function, and the weird thing is that the last printf works only with a escape sequence and then raise the segmentation fault.

¡Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `c` all arguments to functions are passed by value (including pointers). If you want `open_file` to modify the `file` from `main`, you need to accept a `FILE ** ppFile`, and modify it with `*ppFile = ...`.

Comment: The pointer inside the function is a copy of the pointer from main, so it can't be changed that way, you need another level of indirection. `void open_file(FILE **file)` and `*file = fopen(...)` should work. Call it like `open_file(&file)`. You could also remove the `FILE*` argument completely and return a pointer instead. That's what I would usually do since it mimics the way `fopen` works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post fragments of code where we need to guess in what order they need to be put together. Instead post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)